# config.php and web installation

Tags: php, configuration, installation, config

I have problem with installation for website. I want to make website installation but I need form which will insert it in my config.php file.

Here's the config.php file code:

```
$conf = $TMPL = array(); 
$conf['host'] = '';
$conf['user'] = '';
$conf['pass'] = '';
$conf['name'] = '';
$conf['url'] = ''; 
$conf['mail'] = '';
```

I need form which will insert example "localhost" into `$conf['host'] = 'localhost';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="host">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="text" name="pass">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="url">
<input type="text" name="mail">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $host = $_POST['host'];
 $user = $_POST['user'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $url = $_POST['url'];
 $mail = $_POST['mail'];

 $configfile = "config.php";

 file_put_contents($configfile, "<?php 
\$conf = array();  \$conf['host'] = '". $host ."'; \$conf['user'] = '". $user ."'; \$conf['pass'] = '". $pass ."'; \$conf['name'] = '". $name ."'; \$conf['url'] = '". $url ."'; \$conf['mail'] = '". $mail ."';; ");
}
```

Comment: I've tried fwrite, but still it showing error on line 23 file_put_contents.

Comment: \$conf['host'] = "'. $host .'"; 
  \$conf['user'] = "'. $user .'"; 
  \$conf['pass'] = "'. $pass .'"; 
  \$conf['name'] = "'. $name .'"; 
  \$conf['url'] =  "'. $url .'"; 
  \$conf['mail'] = "'. $mail .'";

Comment: Updated the answer, code now works without errors